# How to add Facebook meta tags to cloud hosted images?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to share some images via the Facebook sharer url `"https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php"`.

The images are stored in the cloud in azure blobs, so I have a url that looks like `"https://myapp.blob.core.windows.net/xxxx.gif"`

In order for the Facebook sharer to correctly display the image it's looking for some meta tags, like `"<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>"`

What would be the best way to add those tags to cloud hosted images?

**Options 1**

Build a redirect url that takes the id of image adds the tags then redirects to the cloud url?

Any other ideas?  Would option 1 work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing two different things. The `meta` tags are for web pages, where if just the link to the page is shared, Facebook can then inspect the page and create a rich representation of it in the post by relying on those tags.

If you need to share a link that happens to be to an image, then you can't use `meta` tags. However, you might be able to use share intents to add some context to the link. For example, if you wanted to provide a link on a web page that will allow people to share the link to the image, you could do something like:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=[appId]&link=[url]&picture=[imageUrl]&name=[imageName]&caption=[imageCaption]&description=[imageDescription]&redirect_uri=[redirectUri]
```

That would take the user to a dialog that would allow them to make a post to their Facebook account, with all the provided information prepopulated. The `redirect_uri` tells Facebook where to send them back on your site when done posting.